# Managing two local GIT repos with one remote

Tags: git, github, centos

I have ended up with quiet a mess with my github repo, and I am looking for some advice on how to sort it out and prevent it from happening again in the future. I will start by saying I am a systems guy not a developer, but I am responsible for managing the repos.

My environment looks like this:
1 Development server, 1 production server, and 1 github repo.

My current problem is:
Both dev and production servers are using the same github repo. One of our developers has pushed code directly into the github master, which is currently running on the dev server, in the mean time changes have been made locally to the prod server. The new code on the dev/remote is not production ready and I need to get the local changes from production into github and deployed on the dev server without overwriting the new code on dev.

I think the solution to prevent this from happening again is the make the developer use branches instead of pushing into the master, and not making anymore changes locally on production. Any tips or advice is greatly appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To sort out the current mess:**

1. Get the code from the prod server pushed to GitHub. Since master currently has other stuff in it, we'll push to a new `prod` branch. On the prod server:

   a. `git checkout -b prod` to create a new `prod` branch.

   b. `git commit` to commit your changes to the local prod git repository.

   c. `git push -u origin prod` to push your code up to GitHub.
2. Now let's get that merged into master. On the dev machine:

   a. `git checkout master` and `git pull` to make sure you're up to date.

   b. `git merge prod` to merge the prod branch into the master branch.

   c. `git push` to push the merged master branch up to GitHub.
3. Now, you're left with a `prod` branch that represents production and a `master` branch that contains all your changes. It's up to you if you want to rename these, continue dev work on master, push master to prod, or whatever.

---

**How to avoid this in the future:**

- Never edit code on a production box.
- Any code that gets pushed to production should be tagged with a release version. If you don't have a versioning scheme, you should start. It doesn't need to be fancy - you can just start with 1 and go up from there if you want.
- Implement a release process. For example, master should contain only tested code that's ready to be released. And when the code is released, master is tagged and then the tag is deployed to production. Or something like that. Figure out what works for you.
- In conjunction with the release process, develop policies around where code should be pushed. Most organizations would have devs push to a branch like `feature-a` and then open a pull request to master once the code is tested and ready to go out.

Comment: Thank you...very helpful info. I defiantly need to start doing feature branches. To many times we add feature 1, feature 2, and feature 3 to dev/master and feature 3 ends up having to be deployed without feature 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a new branch, called `production`, pointing to the commit you want to be deployed on your production server, then check out that branch on the production server.

Developers are then free to push to `master` which is the default branch on Git.  To update the production server to a newer version of the code, you can advance the `production` branch to the commit you want to deploy, push `production` to GitHub, then do a `git pull` on the production server.

You can configure GitHub to put restrictions on the `production` branch so that developers can't push to it, and only allow authorized people to modify that branch.